# Mount a volume in docker-compose conditionally

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I have a `docker-compose.yml` configuration. In one of the containers there is a Tomcat server and it has some default `.war` file deployed in `webapps` directory.

I want to have an ability to pass (override) the `war` archive to be deployed by some which resides on the host machine. I think the best would be to have ability somehow switch / override starting `docker-compose`: as a default, I want to run the webapp (`war` file) which is inside the container, but I want to have a possibility to mount a directory from my host (for example during development / debugging) if need be.

Currently, I have the following line in my `docker-compose.yml`, which is commented out if I need the default.

```
volumes:
# By default, there is the latest version of the application already present in the container
# If you want to provider the container with your own .war file, uncomment the following line
# - ./application/webapps:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps
```

Is there a better way how to achieve that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Instead of (not) mounting a volume commenting out that line, I would use https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#example-use-case to run a service extension that specifies a volume.

I do this to tackle two different problems:

- I don't specify a volume when the docker image is meant to run in production and has all the necessary files bundled in it.
- I specify a volume during development, to check live changes.

Answer (score 33):

Since `extend` has been removed in version 3 there's a new way of overriding settings by providing multiple -f params where the next file extends the previous config

The docs are mixed between versions https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#multiple-compose-files

i.e. to run in development mode

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml
```

Where `docker-compose.yml` contains the full config and `docker-compose.dev.yml` only adds a volume

```
services:
  serviceA:
    volumes:
      -.:/usr/local/abc/service
```

Comment: This approach works well where I have some differences on host o/s
```#!/bin/bash
if [ "$(uname -s)" == "Darwin" ]; then
    env_file="env/envMacOS"
    dc_extend=""
else
    env_file="env/envUbuntu"
    dc_extend="-f docker-compose-linux.yml"
fi
# files required by docker but are not in git as they are duplicated
cp ${env_file} .env
cp ../requirements.txt .
echo "***** ENV ${env_file} ****"
docker-compose up -d --build htpc
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml ${dc_extend} up -d ```

Answer (score 4):

Let's say that the .war filename is "app.war"... you could overwrite it using a env variable like this:

```
volumes:
 - ./application/webapps/${APPLICATION_ENV}.war:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/app.war
```

Then when you need to run a different war file just change the `APPPLICATION_ENV` value to the one you need to run and restart the container.

I don't think `docker-compose` does have "conditional volumes", but that way you could change the app.war according with your environment.

Other way would be running a script after the `docker-compose up/start` to overwrite it, and do it only when needed, like:

```
docker-compose exec your-container-name cp /a/volume/path/app.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/app.war
```