# Conditionally mount volumes in docker-compose for several conditions

Tags: docker, configuration, docker-compose, dockerfile, volumes

I use docker and docker compose to package scientific tools into easily/universally executable modules. One example is a docker that packages a rather complicated python library into a container that runs a jupyter notebook server; the idea is that other scientists who are not terribly tech-savvy can clone a github repository, run `docker-compose up` then do their analyses without having to install the library, configure various plugins and other dependencies, etc.

I have this all working fine except that I'm having issues getting the volume mounts to work in a coherent fashion. The reason for this is that the library inside the docker container handles multiple kinds of datasets, which users will store in several separate directories that are conventionally tracked through shell environment variables. (Please don't tell me this is a bad way to do this--it's the way things are done in the field, not the way I've chosen to do things.) So, for example, if the user stores FreeSurfer data, they will have an environment variable named SUBJECTS_DIR that points to the directory containing the data; if they store HCP data, they will have an environment variable HCP_SUBJECTS_DIR. However, they may have both, either, or neither of these set (as well as a few others).

I would like to be able to put something like this in my docker-compose.yml file in order to handle these cases:

```
version: '3'
services:
   my_fancy_library:
      build: .
      ports:
         - "8080:8888"
      environment:
         - HCP_SUBJECTS_DIR="/hcp_subjects"
         - SUBJECTS_DIR="/freesurfer_subjects"
      volumes:
         - "$SUBJECTS_DIR:/freesurfer_subjects"
         - "$HCP_SUBJECTS_DIR:/hcp_subjects"
```

In testing this, if the user has both environment variables set, everything works swimmingly. However, if they don't have one of these set, I get an error about not mounting directories that are fewer than 2 characters long (which I interpret to be a complaint about mounting a volume specified by ":/hcp_subjects").

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41777643/mount-a-volume-in-docker-compose-conditionally) asks basically the same thing, and the answer points to [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#example-use-case), which, if I'm understanding it right, basically explains how to have multiple docker-compose files that are resolved in some fashion. This isn't really a viable solution for my case for a few reasons:

- This tool is designed for use by people who don't necessarily know anything about docker, docker-compose, or related utilities, so expecting them to write/edit their own docker-compose.yml file is a problem
- There are more than just two of these directories (I have shown two as an example) and I can't realistically make a docker-compose file for every possible combination of these paths being declared or not declared
- Honestly, this solution seems really clunky given that the information needed is right there in the variables that docker-compose is already reading.

The only decent solution I've been able to come up with is to ask the users to run a script `./run.sh` instead of `docker-compose up`; the script examines the environment variables, writes out its own `docker-compose.yml` file with the appropriate volumes, and runs `docker-compose up` itself. This also seems somewhat clunky, but it works.

Does anyone know of a way to conditionally mount a set of volumes based on the state of the environment variables when `docker-compose up` is run?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set defaults for environment variable in a `.env`-file shipped alongside with a `docker-compose.yml` <sup>[1]</sup>.

By setting your environment variables to `/dev/null` by default and then handling this case in the containerized application, you should be able to achieve what you need.

### Example

```sh
$ tree -a
.
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
├── .env
└── run.sh
```

#### docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
  test:
    build: .
    environment:
      - VOL_DST=${VOL_DST}
    volumes:
      - "${VOL_SRC}:${VOL_DST}"
```

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine
COPY run.sh /run.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/run.sh"]
```

#### .env

```sh
VOL_SRC=/dev/null
VOL_DST=/volume
```

#### run.sh

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh
set -euo pipefail

if [ ! -d ${VOL_DST} ]; then
  echo "${VOL_DST} not mounted"
else
  echo "${VOL_DST} mounted"
fi
```

#### Testing

Environment variable `VOL_SRC` not defined:

```sh
$ docker-compose up
Starting test_test_1 ... done
Attaching to test_test_1
test_1  | /volume not mounted
test_test_1 exited with code 0
```

Environment variable `VOL_SRC` defined:

```sh
$ VOL_SRC="./" docker-compose up
Recreating test_test_1 ... done
Attaching to test_test_1
test_1  | /volume mounted
```

---

<sup>[1]</sup> https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file

Comment: You can use bash syntax to put the defaults in the docker compose file itself.

volumes:
      - "${VOL_SRC:-/dev/null}:${VOL_DST}"

This will use "/dev/null" as a default value if VOL_SRV env var is not defined. Saves having to define default in separate .env file.

Answer (score 6):

Even though @Ente's answer solves the problem, here is an alternative solution when you have more complex differences between environments.

Docker compose supports [multiple docker-compose files](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/) for **configuration overriding** in different environments.

This is useful if you have different named volumes you need to potentially mount on the same path depending on the environment.

You can modify existing services or even add new ones, for instance:

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3.3'
services:
  service-a:
    image: "image-name"
    volumes:
        - type: volume
          source: vprod
          target: /data
    ports:
     - "80:8080"

volumes:
  vprod:
  vdev:
```

And then you have the override file to change the volume mapping:

```
# docker-compose.override.yml
services:
  service-a:
    volumes:
        - type: volume
          source: vdev
          target: /data
```

When running `docker-compose up -d` both configurations will be merged with the override file taking precedence.

Docker compose picks up `docker-compose.yml` and `docker-compose.override.yml` by default, if you have more files, or files with different names, you need to specify them in order:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.custom.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml up -d
```

Comment: Niceeeeee, this even works with `docker stack deploy`