# Docker-compose dynamically add a volume on runtime

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Snippet of my docker-compose.yml

```
   ports:
      -  "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - "./:/code"
      - "${HOST_FILESTORAGE_PATH}:${DOCKER_FILESTORAGE_PATH}"
```

Problem is, this second volume will only be needed on certain cases, in other cases I don't need it.

Solutions I thought of :

1. If I don't need it, substitute HOST_FILE_STORAGE_PATH and DOCKER_FILESTORAGE_PATH for values that won't make a difference nor break anything, which value could this be?
2. Instead of using variables on docker-compose, is it possible to pass additional volumes when running docker-compose up/run?

Comment: Why don't you simply leave it mounted?
You could have problems inside cotainer because of missing files/directories.

Comment: @EdoardoLobbiani because the HOST_FILESTORAGE_PATH might not exist

Comment: That post may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41777643/mount-a-volume-in-docker-compose-conditionally